# geany custom filetype .sass for syntax highlighting

Tags: css, sass, file-type, lexer, geany

I know there are some answers around, but all incomplete.
Can't get a working .sass syntax highlighting.
I followed all the steps described [in the official guide](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#custom-filetypes),
but no luck.

Steps made:
copied from css file:

```
# cp /usr/share/geany/filetypes.css ~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetypes.sass.conf
```

with the needed .sass.conf extension. 
I've set the

```
extension=.sass
```

(at this point in geany Document menu I can already find the new file type "sass file")

I copied and edited `filetype_extensions.conf` in my `~/.config/geany` adding:

```
SASS=*.sass;
```

Now, I guess only one thing's missing, the lexer_filetype and/or tag_parser declaration
in the former `filetypes.sass.conf`, but I can't find many informations about this.
What are available lexer?
I tried with a simple `lexer_filetype=css` and `tag_parser=css` but nothing.

Any clue from anyone who managed to run this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most names are case-sensitive. It should work if you use `lexer_filetype=CSS`. Also, I'm not positive, but you might want to name the file as `filetypes.SASS.conf` even it's not required (not sure), it's somewhat of a convention for custom filetypes.

Sadly, if you want to find the available lexer filetypes, you'll have to [read the source](https://github.com/geany/geany/blob/1.23.1/src/filetypes.c#L349).

Comment: Yep, that's a start!
Automatically, now, my sass files are recognized.
Anyway, having a complete syntax highlighting it's not a simple task, with indentation and all that. I read it can only be done with a plugin, what do you think?

Comment: It should mostly work if you use CSS lexer as a base, I don't really know SASS but see https://sourceforge.net/p/scintilla/feature-requests/799.

Comment: If you have already opened target files, you have to **`Tools > Reload Configuration`**

Answer (score 1):

geany saves the filetype of an opened file!

If you change the filetype-definitions you must try *another* file to test your new definitions. Closing and reopening the same file is not enough.