# geany custom filetype .svrf for syntax highlighting

Tags: file-type, geany, file-type-associations

I have a similar issue;
I copied and edited `filetype_extensions.conf` in my `~/.config/geany` adding:

```
CALIBRE=*.rul;*.svrf;*.SVRF;*.cal;
```

Then under `~/.config/geany/filedefs` I created following files:

`filetypes.CALIBRE.conf` ==> my custom filetypes

`filetypes.commmon`  ==> I wanted specific colored named_styles

```
# For complete documentation of this file, please see Geany's main documentation
[styling]
comment=svrf_comment
key=svrf_keyword_comment,bold

[settings]
# default extension used when saving files
extension=svrf
lexer_filetype=NONE

[keywords]
# all items must be in one line
svrf=EXT ENC INT EXPAND 


# the following characters are these which a "word" can contains, see documentation
#wordchars=_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789

# single comments, like / in this file
comment_single=//
# multiline comments
#comment_open=/*
#comment_close=*/

# set to false if a comment character/string should start at column 0 of a line, true uses any
# indentation of the line, e.g. setting to true causes the following on pressing CTRL+d
    #command_example();
# setting to false would generate this
#   command_example();
# This setting works only for single line comments
comment_use_indent=true

# context action command (please see Geany's main documentation for details)
context_action_cmd=

[indentation]
#width=4
# 0 is spaces, 1 is tabs, 2 is tab & spaces
#type=1

[build-menu]
# %f will be replaced by the complete filename
# %e will be replaced by the filename without extension
# (use only one of it at one time)
#FT_02_LB=_Lint
#FT_02_CM=jshint "%f"
#FT_02_WD=
#error_regex=([^:]+): line ([0-9]+), col ([0-9]+)
```

However when I open an svrf file type my custom filetypes is not recognized (no specific color while I chose some styling).

If I choose `[styling=C]` and `lexer_filetype=C` I am getting color for "C" code...

I also tried `[styling]` and `lexer_filtype=NONE`, but once again my custom highlight is not recognized.

I alread ready geany manual, as well as looked as some post but none of them is completely answering this subject (on the 2nd overflow link user has mapped to existing filetype hence he's not getting behavior he had wished).

- [geany custom filetype .sass for syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095828/geany-custom-filetype-sass-for-syntax-highlighting/66387664#66387664)
- [Geany: Syntax highlighting for custom filetype for SOME words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37420503/geany-syntax-highlighting-for-custom-filetype-for-some-words?rq=1)

Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue?