# how to force geany recognice custom filetypes and settings?

Tags: customization, geany

I am on linux ubuntu 20.04
geany version:
`geany 1.36 (built on 2020-03-22 with GTK 3.24.14, GLib 2.64.1)`

simplest test possible:

- at tools menu, edit the asm single line comment from ';' to '#'
- reload the configuration files or restart geany
- absolutely nothing happens
- try to root edit related file: /usr/share/geany/filedefs/filetypes.asm
- absolutely nothing happens again

is the config all hardcoded?

none of the related questions and answers helped:
[geany custom filetype .svrf for syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388285/geany-custom-filetype-svrf-for-syntax-highlighting)
[Custom syntax highlighting in Geany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769358/custom-syntax-highlighting-in-geany)
[Make Geany recognize additional file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316547/make-geany-recognize-additional-file-extensions)
...

am I doing something wrong?

as soon I am able to make anything work at all, I will try to add a new filetype with many specific setting, so I just need to at least make anything work at all initially.

Answer (score 0):

My observation: If a file `filetype_extensions.conf` exists in `/usr/share/geany`, then the file in `~/.config/geany` will be ignored. So I do all my settings manually in `/usr/share/geany/filetype_extensions.conf`. Since I do not have any special filedefs, can't tell you if this is true for them too. But I suppose it does.

*(worked with ubuntu 20.03 and geany 1.36; still works with ubuntu 22.04 ans geany 1.38)*

PS: take care to have a copy of your config files, when updating geany. This a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: I needed to modify the highlights and text formatting for pascal. the one that helped a bit was .asm format, but was not good enough. so I tried to customize for pascal (I think) but it did not accept any formatting (and comments delimiter) I tried to configure. But... now I am on 22.04, I just opened geany 1.38 and saw a nice pascal formatting! May be what I asked in the OP already works now (customize formattings), but I had not time to test and conclude this question.

Answer (score 0):

I did it, but have to use a trick:
to create a new filetype for *.asl, the only way I found was to override some other filetype that I will probably never use, I do that at ~/.config/geany/filedefs/
I guess it is because geany 1.38 on ubuntu22.04, is unable to detect new file types.

I chose the 1st "Abaqus" that I have no idea what it is.
at filetype_extensions.conf I put this `Abaqus=*.asl;*.ASL;`
Now, I get all content of the filetype.cpp (that is the most similar to .asl), paste it on filetype.abaqus and uncomment all lines.
At my ~/.config/geany/filedefs/filetype.abaqus, I change to `extension=asl` and restart geany, and it works!
Now, w/o restarting geany I can customize that file to my needs.